# Worklight - EncryptedCache open fails with error status 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am having some problems with EncryptedCache on my HTC One Android phone.
The same code works on another phone and in the browser simulator but fails on my HTC One android phone with an unusual error code.

I am using: Worklight 6.2 
Failing on: HTC one, android 4.4.2 (Cyanogenmod)
Working on: Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II
Working on: browser simulator

WL.EncryptedCache.open fails on my phone and return status 10.. 
(* WL.EncryptedCache.write fails on my phone and return status 6..)

I have also run the sample app from developerworks as-is on my HTC One phone with the same results and error code.
[Sample app link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/EncryptedCacheProject.zip)

Logcat log:

- Captured from Sample app
  1) Destroyed cache
  2) Entered a new key
  3) Opened cache
  4) Got alert error message

Full log can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1696392/logcat_log.txt)

My code is:

```
function wlCommonInit(){

var STORAGE_ID = 'todos';
WL.EncryptedCache.open(STORAGE_ID, true, 
        function(){ //success
            console.log('--> cache opened');
            console.log("--> Loading Angular");
            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                 angular.bootstrap(document, ['todomvc']);
                 //location.hash = "/";
             });
        }, 
        function(status){ //fail
            console.log("WL.EncryptedCache open error status: " + status);
                switch(status){
                case WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_KEY_CREATION_IN_PROGRESS:
                    alert("ERROR: KEY CREATION IN PROGRESS");
                    break;
                case WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_LOCAL_STORAGE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                    alert("ERROR: LOCAL STORAGE NOT SUPPORTED");
                    break;
                case WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_NO_EOC:
                    alert("ERROR: NO EOC");
                    break;
                case WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_COULD_NOT_GENERATE_KEY:
                    alert("ERROR: COULD NOT GENERATE KEY");
                    break;
                case WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_CREDENTIALS_MISMATCH:
                    alert("ERROR: CREDENTIALS MISMATCH");
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("AN ERROR HAS OCCURED. STATUS :: " + status);
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say I cannot currently reproduce this.

1. Installed Worklight Studio 6.2 from the Eclipse marketplace into a fresh copy of Eclipse and a new workspace
2. Downloaded the Encrypted Offline Cache sample project > import to Eclipse
3. Added the Android environment and > Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
4. Installed on device (Nexus 5, Android 4.4)
5. Opened a cache, encrypted some value, closed cache, quit app, re-open, re-open cache, decrypt key, etc etc... all operations seem to pass.

Could you please use Wireshark while you use the app and provide the trace log from there?
In addition, if you could also try the above steps.

Comment: Thanks Idan! I'll check out wireshark and post the tracelog later. meanwhile is there a way to understand what is error status 10 for WL.EncryptedCache.open (and 6 for read) as it's undocumented.

Comment: 10 means the random generator didn't reply back. I assume 6 will happen because of 10.

Comment: I have a log file generated from "Shark for Root" app -> wireshark.. what would be the best way to post it.

Comment: Great! i uploaded it to [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1696392/Wireshark_tracelog.zip) - The capture steps: started to capture -> opened app -> got the alert (status 10) -> closed the app -> stopped capture.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately this is not helpful. Are you at all able to connect to the Worklight Server? From your question, what is SGS2? Is this a device? Are you in fact saying it fails in HTC One, but working in other devices?

Comment: SGS2 is another android phone (Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II) that I have available, the app with Encrypted cache works successfully on it (online and offline). My app has no authentication or adapter relationship with the server (dev on my laptop) and as far as I understand the Sample app doesn't as well. It is failing on HTC One..

Comment: One thing I notice on HTC One, if I disable my mobile data and wifi the error code comes quickly. If I am connected to the network it takes a long time before I get the error. I've had some problems (maybe related) with testing JsonStorage on the same device.. I gave up on it after a while.

Comment: Please update the question accordingly and also add logcat logs. Use the sample project.

Comment: Nothing on the log either... I'll be able to test it on a HTC One device only on Sunday.

Comment: Thank @Idan for helping to test and debug, I have done a wipeout + clean installation of CM11 with the latest build over the weekend and the issue still persists on my HTC One. I have nothing unusual going on my phone, the camera sucks but thats about it!  I will do a bit more experiments on my side and I'm happy to help provide more tests, but I have to move on from Encrypted cache for the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting the same error. My steps were open cache, write, close. Then open again and read. 
The issue was close and open again. I kept the cache open for the entire session and it worked fine. 
Looks like when you destroy cache, you might have to close it and open again to write a new entry. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience! are you getting this on all phones.. mine was happening only on HTC One M7, both on my phone and on an HTC One M7 emulator (genymotion).. However, after upgrading worklight to the latest version (latest 6.2.0.01) and re-building the app it works fine on both phone and emulator.

Comment: I am on Worklight 6.3 actually. I tested only on the emulator. Anyways...great its working!!